# spring web application to be used at command line

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way I can run a Spring Web Application from command line? I checked and found that there is a `.jar` file. Of course it has no `main()` and therefore I can't run it like:

> java -jar Foo-1.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar

Unfortunately I'm not allowed to change the project e.g. to spring-boot.

Comment: You can with Spring Boot.  Spring Boot uses an embedded tomcat instance and can be packaged as a `jar` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to run a Spring Web Application from command line without Spring Boot, you have to use an application server.

A WAR file contains just classes to be used by application server. Springboot provides an embedded application server. You need an external Application server to run your WAR file on e.g. tomcat.

If you know where the application server is installed you can specify the path in your `main()` method and run tomcat as an application (like you do from command line). However you need to copy your WAR to webapps folder first.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your application to spring boot application and you can use the command line to run the web application. Depending on your requirement choose pom.xml packaging as war or jar. If you included JSP, JS files then choose war otherwise jar.

Both the cases you can run it from the command line.